# Не получается подключиться с SSL сертификатом

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, openssl, x509certificate

Привет! У меня есть pfx сертификат, с помощью которого мне надо авторизоваться на определенном URL для получения и отправки данных. Сертификат самоподписанный.

Сделал из него `pem` файлы:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out client_smsgate-in.pem -clcerts
openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out ca_client_smsgate-in.pem -cacerts
```

Затем пробую подключатся:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("myurl.ru")
pem = File.read("client_smsgate-in.pem")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true
http.ca_file = File.read("ca_client_smsgate-in.pem")
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem, 'pass')

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
```

Выдает ошибку:
`lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in 'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

Если поставить `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`, то работает. Подскажите, что не так, ведь я CA серт ему указал?

Comment: Попробуйте соединиться с сервером при помощи `openssl s_client` и посмотреть на отдаваемый сертификат: кем он подписан, нет ли промежуточных УЦ, какие даты и т.п.

Comment: Публичный ключ CA нужен для удостоверения **серверного** сертификата, там он тоже самоподписанный?